# Add a extra property to each item of an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of items called `documents`.  Each item has the same bunch of properties.  I wanted to add an additional property to each item called `serviceShortCode`.  I wrote the following code to achieve this

```
documents = _.map(documents, function (doc) {
                return _.extend({                    
                    serviceShortCode: View.getServiceName(doc.publishedIn)      
                });
            });
```

Once this code finishes executing I get an array of objects with only the `serviceShortCode`, all other properties have vanished.

Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the document from the extend call.

Change

```
return _.extend({                    
    serviceShortCode: View.getServiceName(doc.publishedIn)
});
```

To

```
return _.extend(doc, {                    
    serviceShortCode: View.getServiceName(doc.publishedIn)
});
```

Or, alternatively

```
return _.extend({}, doc, {                    
    serviceShortCode: View.getServiceName(doc.publishedIn)
});
```

to ensure the original objects remain unmodified.